# How do I set up a world that is only daytime, on the same server as one with a normal day/night cycle?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

I am running a Minecraft server ([Spigot](https://www.spigotmc.org)) on my desktop, for me and my friends. Some of my friends want to play standard Survival mode, and some want to play Creative.

For this, I installed [Multiverse](https://github.com/Multiverse/Multiverse-Core/wiki) and added a second world that is just flat terrain with the `CREATIVE` game mode. Obviously, if all they want to do is build creatively, they would want it to always be daytime. So for this, in the Creative world, I set up a command block with `time set day`, triggered by a daylight sensor. This worked fantastically!

However, when I went back to the Survival world, I was dismayed to find that the command block in the Creative world affected the Survival world, too, making it never be nighttime. This isn't how we wanted to play in the Survival world, obviously.

So my question is, **how do I make the Creative world always day, and the Survival world cycle normally?**

---

[I tried searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=spigot+multiverse+time+set) for it, but I can't find any answers that seem confident. [Some mention](https://bukkit.org/threads/multiverse-always-day.182229/) a plugin called *Timeshift*, but it seems to have [not been maintained](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/timeshift) since 2012.

The closest I got was [Issue #79](https://github.com/Multiverse/Multiverse-Core/issues/79) on their GitHub: "Request: Per-World Time".  This was closed saying this:

> Each World has it's own time, whatever plugin or command you're using to change time is doing it wrong if it's setting all worlds.
>
> We can look into adding the ability to keep it a certain time constantly per world, so one world is always day and the other is always night set.

So this is promising; it seems that it's totally possible to do what I want... I just can't figure out how.

---

I only have these mods installed:

- Multiverse
- [Dynmap](https://github.com/webbukkit/dynmap/wiki)
- [LuckPerms](https://github.com/lucko/LuckPerms/wiki)

Comment: A simple plugin could do this for you. Something like [`setTime()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/World.html#setTime-long-) in a repeating task should suffice.

Comment: @dly I'd rather not write software for this... if that's possible

Comment: I haven't worked with that functionality, but WorldGuard has a region flag called *time-lock*, which does not actually change or lock the time, but it pretends to. So it's daylight for the players in a certain region with this flag enabled, while it may be actually dark outside. Could this solve your problem?

Comment: @dly I'll look into it!

Comment: Why do you need this to be on the same server? Setting up a second server isn't hard at all if you have one already.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy sounds like you have a great Answer! Please go into detail :3

Answer (score 1):

## Don't use your main server for tests, even a small one

Using other worlds on your main server for tests is a really bad idea. Firstly, it does not give you a fully independent test/building environment (many values, like time, are changed globally, server resets are done globally, etc.). Secondly, if you break something on a test/building server, it doesn't damage the main one, while a test world might make the damage also touch your main environment.

Thirdly, a separate test server allows you to give full creative mode permissions to all the players, while it is rather dangerous on your main one, even if you think that you can really trust everyone who plays with you. Yes, your permission management plugins can malfunction, and I have seen Bad Things Happening because of that.

Once you have learned to set up one dedicated server, setting up another one is exactly Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, and some changes in the *server.properties* file (Port, server name).

World Edit is a plugin that allows you to easily move structures from one place to another after you set it up.

Whenever I need to test something in Minecraft, I simply  set up a testing server, then stop and/or delete it when it is no longer needed.

Of course, you can only use this solution if your hardware can handle two servers at the same time.

My answer is true even for a small server for a couple of friends, but is especially needed on any server that hosts more than, like, 7 people. Playing Creative and playing Survival are basically two different games, and it is better if they are played on two different servers that borrow each others' results when needed.

Having two distinct servers also solves a problem of moving stuff from one place to another. Players just log on to the server they choose at the moment, and all you need to move a structure on your main server is copy and paste a schematic via WorldEdit. Don't forget to check the amount of pricy blocks they use if you have an economy set up, for example, someone might try to sneak in a bunch of diamond blocks.

Comment: I should probably have specified... this is a teensy server. It's just me and maybe 1-3 of my close friends. We just want a way to play together, sometimes Survival, sometimes Creative. If this were a big public server I'd never perform tests in production :P

Comment: So, Multiverse handles multiple servers now, right? I can just set up a  portal or teleport command block to get people from one to the other?

Comment: @Supuhstar Updated my answer accordingly. :)